# Measure Theory: Properties of Sets and Measures in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A, B_1, B_2, \ldots \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $A \subseteq \limsup_{k \to \infty} B_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(B_k) < \infty$. Which of the following statements are true?

(a) $\mu(A) > 0$.

(b) $\mu(A) = 0$.

(c) Every point of $A$ belongs to infinitely many of the $B_k$.

(d) Every point of $A$ belongs to all except possibly finitely many of the $B_k$.

My thoughts so far are:
We define $\limsup_{k \to \infty} B_k = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty B_k$.

a) If $\mu(A) = 0$ $\iff$ $A = \emptyset$, then $\emptyset \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty B_k$. This seems possible to me, I cannot find a counterexample that would show it is false.

b) If $\mu(A) > 0 \iff A \neq \emptyset$, then there exists $B \subseteq A \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty B_k$. This does also seem possible, but obviously only either a or b are true, so here I could use a counterexample if someone has one.

c-d) If $A = \emptyset$, then both (c) and (d) are true. Hence, let $A \neq \emptyset$, and let $x \in A$. Then, $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty B_k$ implies $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$, where $C_n := \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty B_k$. Hence, each $C_n$ contains infinitely many $B_k$. Hence, the intersection of $C_n$ contains infinitely many $B_k$ as well. However, it must not hold that $\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty B_k\right)^c = \bigcup_{n=i}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty B_k^c$ is finite. Hence, (d) is false.

Comment: Your definition of $\limsup$ is wrong, it should be $\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{k=n}^\infty B_k$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are more hypothesis on the measure? In the next I will suppose that $\mu$ is a probability measure.

So, if $\mu$ is a probability measure, or a finite measure, then Borel-Cantelli lemma's tell us that $\mu(\limsup B_k) =0$ and since $A \subset \limsup B_k$, then $\mu(A)=0$. Note in particular that you state something that is false in general. If $\mu(A)=0$, then $A$ is not necessarily the empty set.
As an example you can consider the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. In fact the measure of every countable set, like the integers, is equal to zero, but they are not empty.

Furthermore, every $ x \in \limsup B_k$ belongs to all but finitely many $B_k$, which is assertion (d). To see this, consider the $C_n$ you defined, i.e. $C_n = \bigcup_{k \geq n} B_k$. Suppose $x \in \limsup B_k = \bigcap_{n \geq 0} C_n$. Now if there are infinitely many $B_k$ such that $x$ does not belong to them, I can riordinate the $B_k$ in a way such that $x \not\in B_k$ for every $k\geq N$. This means that $x \not\in C_N$, which is absurd because $x \in \limsup B_k$ and so it belongs to all $C_n$. then Since (d) implies (c) they are both true.

Comment: In the question, $\mu$ is not necessarily a finite measure. Instead there is the condition that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(B_k)$ is finite. This also implies that $\mu(\limsup B_k) =0$ since $$\mu(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k) \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu(B_k) \to 0$$ as $n\to\infty.$